# Different regex behavior in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a simple code snippet to search a target word and preceding words:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
txt = u"Min bil är trasig. Det är det också förbundet med ett sjukhus"
tag = u"(förbundet)"
pat = u'(?:\\w+[ \\t,]+){0,2}'+ tag 
res = re.finditer(pat,txt,re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
for i in res:
    print i.group()
```

When I run this code using Python 2.7, I am getting only the word 'förbundet'.
When I run the same code using Python 3.5, I am getting  'det också förbundet'. This is, the expected behavior (get up to two words before the target). What is causing the error in Python 2.7?
In the real code, when I define the search pattern I cannot use the raw text format because, the search pattern is defined in a loop (that is I have to escape manually) where I go through a list of of targets words and I built a new search pattern for each target word.

Comment: You must pass the `re.U` flag in Python 2.x. Try replacing the `re.MULTILINE` with `re.U` (the `re.M` flag looks redundant here since there is no `^` and `$` in your pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the `re.U` / `re.UNICODE` flag in Python 2.x that is on by default in Python 3.x to make the shorthand character class Unicode aware. Replace the `re.MULTILINE` with `re.U` (the `re.M` flag looks redundant here since there is no `^` and `$` in your pattern).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
txt = u"Min bil är trasig. Det är det också förbundet med ett sjukhus"
tag = u"(förbundet)" pat = ur'(?:\w+[ \t,]+){0,2}'+ tag
res = re.finditer(pat,txt,re.IGNORECASE|re.U)
for i in res:
    print i.group().encode("utf8")
```

See the [Python 2.7.10 demo](https://ideone.com/YXfV8d).

Note that using raw string literals can help you reduce double backslashes to single backslashes in the regex pattern.